# In Eigen c++, how to multiply each row of NxM matrix by a vector of Nx1 scalars?

Tags: c++, eigen3

for example, I have:

```
Matrix<double,5,2,RowMajor> points;
Matrix<double,5,1> scalars;
```

What I want is equavalent to:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;++i){
  points.row(i)*=scalars(i);
}
```

Are there oneliner that can achieve this?

I alreay tried rowwise and array but cannot get it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one-liner is as follows:

```
points.array().colwise() *= scalars.array();
```

Because the Array operations are always component-wise.

I thought that `.colwise().cwiseProduct(scalars)` should also work, but it apparently doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You want to perform multiplication element-wise by cols, such kind of operations are suppoted by `Array`.

Oneliner version:

```
std::for_each(points.colwise().begin(),points.colwise().end(),
   [&](auto&& col){ col.array() *= scalars.array().col(0); });
```

Twoliners version:

```
points.array().col(0) *= scalars.array().col(0);
points.array().col(1) *= scalars.array().col(0);
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oyCYcr)